# Set Cursor Position to end of text in contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, cursor-position

I have two issues in following scinario:

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true">
   <font face="arial"> this test text </font>
</div>
```

When i replace the text of font tag by another text cursor position set to initial position i want cursor position at the end of text in content editable.
Also when i remove full text from contenteditable div it removes font tag also, but i want to keep font tag intact. Also i can't set contenteditable to font tag bcoz it is dynamic.

Comment: `<font>` tag was deprecated in HTML 4.01, aka 13 years ago. Use CSS

Comment: @AlexThomas: I think some browsers produce `<font>` elements when using `document.execCommand()`.

Comment: @both guys as i said Font tag coming from third party.. and i have retain it bcause i have to return text with FOnt tag...